# Validity of Fresnel Approximation

Tags: optics, diffraction

This is in relation to the scalar diffraction theory described in the Introduction to Fourier Optics by J. Goodman. A sufficient condition for Fresnel approximation to be valid is that the higher-order phase terms in the binomial expansion of the propagation distance can be ignored. However, I would like to know if Fresnel approximation is still valid when the aperture size is comparable to the distance of propagation -- a regime where higher-order phase terms of the expansion can't be necessarily ignored. This confusion arises from the fact that eventually, all we care about is the integral, and if the higher-order phase terms have minimum effect on it, then the approximation should be valid. Is my understanding correct? If so, what condition on the initial field(that is propagated) allows such approximation to be valid?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a technical issue and there is no simple answer that covers all cases. The higher-order terms in the integral are more sensitive to the higher spatial frequencies, so the answer will depend on the whether or not the aperture has sharp edges. If the edges are not abrupt then the Fresnel approximation is more successful.

For the circular aperture with abrupt edges, I did a study of this many years ago, which you can find here:

https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAA.6.001809

Strictly, that study was about how to simplify the calculation of this case, and then, having done so, make it more accurate in the near field.

A quick google just now on the theme of Fresnel approximation turned up many papers so clearly people are still working on it, which confirms that it is indeed a rather rich subject.